# Label pcap files with comments

Tags: dataset, pcap

I would like to create a dataset of network captures containing different scenarios, both normal and attacks. I have executed attacks and captured the traffic in .pcap files, and I would like to label as attacks only the frames that belong to a particular source identified by IP or MAC.

I have been trying to add comments in the .pcap files and saving the output as .pcapng, which supports comments on the frames. Using the tool editcap, it is possible to add comments to the frames, but I have not found a way to do it only for selected sources. I have also tried with Wireshark, but the captures are very large, 5GB or 6GB, and it has problems loading the file, and it is not possible to add comments to several frames at once.

Is there any tool to accomplish this, or should I create my own script?